# 4G Fail Over Home Network

Tags: networking, router, failover

I am installing home network from scratch and would like to install failover 4G system (mainly for IP camera surveillance system). With lots of Googling I came up with the plan which is included in the enclosed picture link.

Shortly, I have GPON router from ISP, which I would connect to Dual WAN router. To the same router I would connect LTE receiver and the router would be set-up with FailOver option. This 2WAN router would connect to a Switch which would distribute internal network to everything (IP cameras, APs, PCs, etc.) So here are my questions:

1. Will this work? Any general recommendations?
2. For dual WAN router I have my eye on EdgeRouterX. What do you think?
3. On the other hand, somehow I am sure there must be a hardware which would combine 2WAN with LTE router. so that there is one less piece. Can you recommend anything? I am looking at [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NYWVFY3), but I am not sure it is what I need.
4. If not, can you recommend 4G router? **IMPORTANT: Both above options must work with European SIM card** (AFAIK it is different from US one?).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqYBK.jpg

Answer (score 0):

1. This design is fine.
2. Ubiquity is great for the price, but you will need to make sure the firmware is updated. I also like Mikrotik, but the configuration is more complex.
3. Although integrated devices have less bulk, they create single point of failure and are more difficult to troubleshoot.

What to think about is, what type of data you are going to push through 4G and if your data plan will be sufficient. Maybe you need only limited services over 4G. In that case you will need to look for options with firewall and/or DPI.